# How to use OpenGL to draw a text over a Android MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, native

I have a cpp code implementing a [media player](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/refs/tags/android-12.0.0_r15/media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp) behavior on Android.

I'm using the media player for playing a mp4 file however, I need to draw text above this.

For testing purposes, I've already tried to do as [drawText()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-12.0.0_r15/cmds/bootanimation/BootAnimation.cpp#850) function from [BootAnimation.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-12.0.0_r15/cmds/bootanimation/BootAnimation.cpp) however without success.

I'm guessing there is some OpenGL calls I'm missing. Is there some call to be added inside drawText() for it to draw above the mp4?

```java
void BootAnimation::drawText(const char* str, const Font& font, bool bold, int* x, int* y) {
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);  // Allow us to draw on top of the animation
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, font.texture.name);
    const int len = strlen(str);
    const int strWidth = font.char_width * len;
    if (*x == TEXT_CENTER_VALUE) {
        *x = (mWidth - strWidth) / 2;
    } else if (*x < 0) {
        *x = mWidth + *x - strWidth;
    }
    if (*y == TEXT_CENTER_VALUE) {
        *y = (mHeight - font.char_height) / 2;
    } else if (*y < 0) {
        *y = mHeight + *y - font.char_height;
    }
    int cropRect[4] = { 0, 0, font.char_width, -font.char_height };
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = str[i];
        if (c < FONT_BEGIN_CHAR || c > FONT_END_CHAR) {
            c = '?';
        }
        // Crop the texture to only the pixels in the current glyph
        const int charPos = (c - FONT_BEGIN_CHAR);  // Position in the list of valid characters
        const int row = charPos / FONT_NUM_COLS;
        const int col = charPos % FONT_NUM_COLS;
        cropRect[0] = col * font.char_width;  // Left of column
        cropRect[1] = row * font.char_height * 2; // Top of row
        // Move down to bottom of regular (one char_heigh) or bold (two char_heigh) line
        cropRect[1] += bold ? 2 * font.char_height : font.char_height;
        glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, cropRect);
        glDrawTexiOES(*x, *y, 0, font.char_width, font.char_height);
        *x += font.char_width;
    }
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);  // Return to the animation's default behaviour
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

PS: this is no android app, so it won't be done in [app layer](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bootanimation.cpp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/cmds/bootanimation/BootAnimation.cpp;l=1?q=Bootanimation.cpp&sq=&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) use of OpenGL ES changed a bit and now it's using a more modern way to deal with graphics.

That being said, I found that my case would need a some abstraction as done [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/cmds/bootanimation/BootAnimation.cpp;drc=9ef19b85cbc8ccc55ef8607c9420967443b20461;l=511). Basic OpenGL manipulation, as use of common vertex and fragment shaders (position and color, really nothing different from fundamentals) and VBO/VAO for data buffering and glDrawArrays is enough for my usage.

I still need to understand and apply some texture and understand the best way (in my scenario) for manipulate text, however I think that is the all.